# Why does binary saving of array in a file works? [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays, file, binary, export

C++ newbie here.

I'm trying to figure out the following line that writes a buffer into a file:

```
fOut.write((char *)&_data, sizeof(_data));
```

_data = array of integers...

I have a couple of questions:

1. Is `&_data` the address to the first element of the array?
2. Whatever address it is, does that mean that we only save the address of the array? then how come I still can access the array after I free it?
3. Shouldn't I pass `sizeof(_data)*arrLength`? what is the meaning of passing the size of int (in this case) and not the size of the entire array?
4. What does casting into `char*` mean when dealing with addresses?

I would really appreciate some clarifications.

Comment: Better show the _exact_ definition of `_data`. And I'm suspicious about the `&` anyway, is this exact, working code?

Comment: _data is just an array... saved on the heap. and yes, it works :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to your comment, the array must be automatic or static storage duration in order for `sizeof` to work.

1. It should be just `(char*)_data`.  The name of an array implicitly converts to a pointer to the first element.
2. No, `write` expects a pointer, and stores the content found at that location, not the location's address.
3. No.  Since `_data` is an array, `sizeof (_data)` is the cumulative size of all elements in the array.  If `_data` were a pointer (such as when an array is dynamically allocated on the heap), you would want `numElems * sizeof(_data[0])`.  Multiplying the size of a pointer by the number of elements isn't helpful.
4. It means that the content at that address will be treated as a series of individual bytes, losing whatever numeric meaning it might have had.  This is often done to perform efficient bulk copy of data, either to and from a file, or with `memcpy`/`memmove`.  The data type should be POD (plain old data) or you'll get unexpected results.

If `_data` is a pointer to an array allocated from the heap, as your comment suggests, then the code is badly broken.  In that case, you are saving just the address, and it may appear to work if you load the file back into the same instance of your program, but that's just because it's finding the data still in memory at the same address.  The data wouldn't actually be in the file, and if you re-started the program before loading the file, you'd find that the data was gone.  Make the changes I mentioned in both (1) and (3) in order to save the complete array regardless of whether it's allocated automatic, static, or dynamically.

Comment: Why it needs to be `automatic` or `static` for `sizeof` to work ? Source ?

Comment: @Muggen: Because dynamic allocation returns a pointer, and `sizeof` a pointer isn't the size of the content.  Don't bring the `auto` keyword into this though, it doesn't mean automatic storage duration any more.

Comment: Fixed the `auto`. Ok I see what you mean. +1

Comment: I'm sorry for misleading all of you. the array is dynamic, so _data is a pointer to an array. The reason I got confused is that the code worked almost perfectly in the way I mentioned in the first post. What I eventually did was: fout.write((char *)_data, sizeof(T)*_size);

Answer (score 1):

> What does casting into char* means
>   when dealing with addresses?

Imagine this simple example

```
int x = 12;
char * z = (char *)&x;
```

And assume an architecture where `int` is 4 bytes long. From the C++ Standard `sizeof(char)==1`.

On the expression `char * z` the `char *` part, you could say that is being used for pointer arithmetic

on the Second line of the example I gave, what happens is that `z` now points to the first (out of 4 bytes) that `x` has. Doing a `++z;` will make `z` point to the Second Byte of the (in my example) 4byte `int`

You could say that the left part of a declaration is used for pointer arithmetic, to simplify things. a `++(char *)` would move you by one byte, while a `++(int *)` would move you by the corresponding number of bytes `int` occupies on the memory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. No, write uses this address as the first location, and reads through sizeof(_data) writing the whole array
3. sizeof(_data) will return the size of the entire array not the same as sizeof(int)
4. Means the data will be read byte by byte, this is the pointer required by write as it writes in binary format(byte by byte)

Comment: thank you but... I already checked, no matter what size my array is, sizeof(_data) returns 4... so I guess it is the size of int.

Comment: And I wrote now cout << &_data << endl << &_data[0] << endl;    and it outputs two entirely different addresses.

Comment: @user, what is the type of _data ?

Comment: Are you dynamically allocating the array? In that case _data is actually a pointer and the above answers would change. If _data is a pointer to a dynamic array on the heap sizeof(_data)=4, &_data != &_data[0] because one is the address where pointer address is stored, and the other is the address of first element in array

Comment: As a dynamically allocated array, _data is being used improperly and your code is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

> is &_data the address to the first element of the array?

Yes, it is. <strike>This is the usual way to pass a "reference" to an array in C and C++. If you passed the array itself as a parameter, the whole array contents would be copied, which is usually wasteful and unnecessary.</strike> *Correction:* You can pass either `&_data`, or just `_data`. Either way, the array does not need to be copied to the stack.

> whatever address it is, does that mean that we only save the address of the array? then how come I still can access the array after I delete him from the memory?

No, the method uses the address it gets to read the array contents; just saving the memory address would be pointless, as you point out.

> Shouldn't I pass sizeof(_data)*arrLength? I mean...
>   what is the logic of passing the size
>   of int (in this case) and not the size
>   of the entire array?

No, `sizeof(_data)` is the size of the array, not of one member. No need to multiply by length.

> What does casting into char* means when dealing with addresses?

Casting to char* means that the array is accessed as a list of bytes; that's necessary for accessing and writing the raw values.

Comment: If you pass an array name, you're passing the pointer.  Unless it's wrapped in a class of some sort, the array itself isn't passed.

Comment: @David: Yes, thanks for the correction. I mixed up the behaviour for arrays and structs. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, &_data is the address of the first element of your array.
2) No, write() writes the number bytes you have specified via sizeof(_data) starting at address &_data
3) You would pass sizeof(int)*arrLength if _data is a *pointer* to an array, but since it *is* an array sizeof() returns the correct size.
4) don't know. ;)

Answer (score 0):

read this : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/write/

1. should be.
2. if you call "fstream.write(a,b)" then it writes b bytes starting from location a into the file (i.e. what the address is pointing at);
3. it should be the size in bytes or chars .
4. not much, similar to casting stuff to byte[] in more civilized languages.

By the way, it will only work on simple arrays with simple values inside them...

**i suggest you look into the >> << operators .**